# Reshape Melt - Easiest way to refer to correct ID and MEASURED columns

Tags: r, reshape

### Problem

I want to melt a dataframe with many columns, using very little typing.

The dataframes that I work with often have many columns of which IDs may be numbers, characters or factors. The IDs and MEASURED columns generally aren't contiguous.

What do I do?

Is there something like `melt(mydata, id=c(1:7,9,10,12), measured=c(8,11)`?

### Example

I have a dataframe that looks something like the following

```
id1 <- round(abs(rnorm(5)),1)
id2 <- sample(letters,5)
id3 <- sample(letters,5)
id4 <- sample(letters,5)
id5 <- sample(letters,5)
id6 <- round(abs(rnorm(5)),1)
id7 <- sample(letters,5)
m1 <-  round(abs(rnorm(5)),1)
id8 <- sample(letters,5)
id9 <- sample(letters,5)
m2 <-  round(abs(rnorm(5)),1)
id10 <- sample(letters,5)    
mydata <- data.frame(id1,id2,id3,id4,id5,id6,id7,m1,id8,id9,m2,id10)
```

Resulting in....

```
  id1 id2 id3 id4 id5 id6 id7  m1 id8 id9  m2 id10
1.5   c   i   r   m 1.8   f 0.1   x   g 0.7    t
0.4   n   o   q   b 0.9   s 0.1   f   x 0.0    m
1.6   b   g   s   i 0.7   i 0.5   d   z 1.3    b
0.6   g   s   j   k 0.3   j 0.8   p   i 0.4    d
0.5   z   e   i   s 0.4   r 0.8   k   y 0.9    a
```

Where "id" means columns that I want as IDs and "m" means columns that I want as MEASURED variables. NOTE: my columns don't actually follow the pattern "id_" or "m_" - they could be anything.

How do I go about correctly and quickly getting melt to work as I intend?

I'd prefer not to have to write out

```
melt(mydata, id = c("id1","id2",etc, etc, etc), measured = c("m1","m2))
```

If all my ID variables were characters, I know I could just write

```
melt(mydata, measured = c("m1","m2))
```

But since I have character/factor ID columns, I get this (incorrect) output

```
x   id2 id3 id4 id5 id7 id8 id9 id10 variable value
1    c   i   r   m   f   x   g    t      id1   1.5
2    n   o   q   b   s   f   x    m      id1   0.4
3    b   g   s   i   i   d   z    b      id1   1.6
4    g   s   j   k   j   p   i    d      id1   0.6
5    z   e   i   s   r   k   y    a      id1   0.5
6    c   i   r   m   f   x   g    t      id6   1.8
7    n   o   q   b   s   f   x    m      id6   0.9
8    b   g   s   i   i   d   z    b      id6   0.7
9    g   s   j   k   j   p   i    d      id6   0.3
10   z   e   i   s   r   k   y    a      id6   0.4
11   c   i   r   m   f   x   g    t       m1   0.1
12   n   o   q   b   s   f   x    m       m1   0.1
13   b   g   s   i   i   d   z    b       m1   0.5
14   g   s   j   k   j   p   i    d       m1   0.8
15   z   e   i   s   r   k   y    a       m1   0.8
16   c   i   r   m   f   x   g    t       m2   0.7
17   n   o   q   b   s   f   x    m       m2   0.0
18   b   g   s   i   i   d   z    b       m2   1.3
19   g   s   j   k   j   p   i    d       m2   0.4
20   z   e   i   s   r   k   y    a       m2   0.9
```

If my dataframe ID and MEASURED columns were contiguous like this

```
mydata <- data.frame(id1,id2,id3,id4,id5,id6,id7,id8,id9,id10,m1,m2)
```

then I'd have an easy time using ranges like

```
melt(mydata, id=1:10, measured = 11:12)
```

But what do I do if my ID/Measured columns aren't contiguous?

In all of the documentation that I've seen on reshape, including Hadley's papers/presentations, I haven't seen how to easily do this.

I'm sure I'm missing something very simple here...

Comment: The only thing missing in the initial code was a closing paren.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to condition on something, be it a pattern in the column name, the column's class, or some lists you populated earlier in your code.  R can't magically figure out which columns are which.

Comment: That's a neat trick, I wouldn't have thought of that! Unfortunately, my columns don't actually follow a pattern like "id_" and "m_". I've updated my question to make this clear.

Comment: @Tommy O'Dell - perhaps you could change the names to have some pattern then. alternatively, you could use the [] function to change the order of your variables to be continuous.

Comment: @richiemorrisroe - that would involve as much typing as referring to the columns like `melt(mydata, id = c("id1","id2",etc, etc, etc), measured = c("m1","m2))`. Surely there's some shortcut like `melt(mydata, id=c(1:7,9,10,12), measured=c(8,11)`?

Comment: @Tommy - yes there is, see ?melt.data.frame for details.

Comment: @Tommy your example, `melt(mydata, id=c(1:7,9,10,12), measured=c(8,11))` works.

Comment: R doesn't seem to like `c(1:7,9,10)`. I just thought to try `c(c(1:7),9,10)` and voila, it worked. I know it's not reshape related, but that just type of example just hasn't shown up in any of documentation/tutorials that I could find.

Comment: Ignore my comment above. `c(1:7,9,10` really does work. I think I need a break.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I  just realised that I can just nest my c's like this

```
melt(mydata, id=c(c(1:7),9,10,12)
```

Sorry to have overcomplicated the question :-\

EDIT: Wow. I thought I tried c(1:7,9,10,12) and R complained. But I try it now it's fine. It's been a loooooooong day.